# How to export result of sql statement with psql as compressed file?

Tags: postgresql

How can I export the following statment into a compressed file, eg `gzip`, instead of `csv`?:

```
psql -h database -U username - d database -A -F"," -f myfile.sql -o targetfile.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output to `gzip`:

```
psql -h database -U username - d database -A -F"," -f myfile.sql | gzip > targetfile.csv.gz
```

Comment: @membersound: you have to install it then. `psql` does not support compression by itself, you need an external tool to compress the output.